# Finding existence(or non existence) of spanning tree with a specific degree on a specific vertex

Tags: graphs, spanning-trees

Given an undirected graph $G=(V,E)$, and vertex $v\in V$ and a number $k\in \mathbb{N}$, find an algorithm to find whether there exists a spanning tree of $G$ in which $v$ satisfies $d(v)=k$

I've narrowed the solution to 3 situations, in $G$: $d(v)<k , \\d(v)=k\\d(v)>k$

When $d(v)<k$, it is clear that there cannot exist a spanning tree of $G$ such that $d(v)=k$, since $d(v)$ was never of value $k$ to begin with.

When $d(v)>k$, we know that we can create a graph $G'$ in which we remove a finite amount of edges $i$ in such a matter that we reduce $d(v)$ to be $k$, and check whether $G'$ is connected or not (we can use BFS), since $d(v)\leq |V|$, the complexity would be $O(|V|\cdot (|V|+|E|))$, however I feel this is extremly inefficient.

For the case where $d(v)=k$ in $G$, I am uncertain on how to proceed.

EDIT: I've managed to update the case where $d(v)>k$ to be in linear time:

if $d(v)>k$, we'll have to remove edges from the graph.

We'll perform $DFS$ on $v$, since $d(v)>k$ there will be back edges, we can (in linear time) count how many back edges are going into(or out of) $v$, if the number of back edges is greater than $m-k$ where $|E|=m$, we can remove $m-k$ back edges from $G$, if the number of back edges is smaller than $m-k$, there cannot be a spanning tree in which $d(v)=k$.

The updated solution to the case was given to me by a colleague, I dont completely understand it yet I am trying to wrap my head around it.

About the case where $d(v)=k$, I am still uncertain.

Comment: Why can't you just run an MST algorithm in case $d(v) = k$? Or better yet if you do not need an MST, a BFS starting from $v$ to see if the graph is connected which would imply that there is a tree that spans all vertices, hence an MST algorithm will find one that minimizes the total weight.

Comment: The question asks for a linear time complexity in all cases, I've edited my answer for the case in which $d(v)>k$ with a linear solution.
MST finding algorithms run in $O(nlogn)$

Comment: Please see my edited comment. And maybe include that running time requirement in the question

Comment: @Russel Please note that this problem doesnt necessarily discuss MSTs, but spanning trees in general.

Comment: So I think running BFS starting from $v$ and checking if all vertices are reachable will suffice when the degree of $v$ in $G$ is $k$, since a BFS will force all edges of $v$ to be part of the BFS tree rooted at $v$, which will be a spanning tree if all vertices will be reached from $v$

Comment: @Russel I do not think this is correct, $BFS$ might not necessarily choose the edges from neighbors of $v$ to $v$, but rather pick otherwise.

Comment: I don't seem to understand your concern

Comment: What if $d(v)>k$ in $G$? Performing $BFS$ from $v$ doesnt guarntee that in the spanning tree we'll get $d(v)=k$. where there could be a spanning tree in which $d(v)=k$

Comment: I think you misunderstood my idea, I am proposing the BFS at $v$ for the case of $d(v) =k$. You mentioned you already have the other two cases covered.

Comment: when $d(v)=k$, how can we ensure that will be $v$'s degree in the spanning tree? (BFS wont necessarily pick all of $v$'s edges)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142054/discussion-between-russel-and-aishgadol).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, verify that $G$ is indeed connected, otherwise say no.

Second, if $G - v$ (the graph after deleting $v$) has more than $k$ components, we can say no.

Pick any $k$ neighbors of $v$ with the restriction that you pick at least one from each component of $G-v$ and mark them.  The edges from $v$ to these marked vertices are in the spanning tree.

For each connected component $C$ of $G-v$, pick a marked vertex $x$.  Run a DFS from $x$ and pick the edges you traverse as long as you see an unvisited vertex.  If you meet a visited vertex, you ignore the edge.  If you meet a *marked* vertex, simply do not put that edge into the spanning tree.

Comment: The use of components here is a nice touch. What's the idea for the last part? Wouldn't the component be enough?

Comment: My apologies, that was not very well explained.  When you run DFS, simply do not add the edges to the marked vertices (except the starting point) to the spanning tree.